# How to call controller method from custom directive in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives

### UI

```
    <div class="row" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="multiselect">
        <div  class="col-md-2">
            <div id="lob" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" options="lobs" attrfilterprojectsonlob="getProjects"
                 selected-model="lobsSelected" checkboxes="true">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div  class="col-md-2">
            <div id="projects" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" extra-settings="dropdownSetting" options="projects"
                 selected-model="projectsSelected" checkboxes="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Angular Controller

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myModule', ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
    myApp.controller('multiselect', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.lobsSelected = [];
        $scope.lobs = [];
        $scope.projectsSelected = [];
        $scope.projects = [];
        $scope.dropdownSetting = {
            scrollable: true,
            scrollableHeight: '200px'
        }


        $http.get('Home/GetALLLOB').then(function (data) {
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                $scope.lobs.push({ id: value.N_LevelID, label: value.T_LevelName }
                );
            });
        })


        $http.get('Home/GetAllProjects').then(function (data) {
            debugger;
            angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                $scope.projects.push({ id: value.N_LevelID, label: value.T_LevelName }
                );
            });
        })


        $scope.getProjects = function (selectedId) {
            debugger;
            var parentId = id;
            $http.get('Home/GetAllProjects', { params: { "parentId": selectedId } })
                .then(function (data) {
                angular.forEach(data.data, function (value, index) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.projects.push({ id: value.N_LevelID, label: value.T_LevelName }
                    );
                });
                })
            .catch(function (data) {
                console.error('Gists error', data.status, data.data);
            })
        }

    }])
```

### Directive : - Please ignore fn_template()

```
'use strict';

var directiveModule = angular.module('angularjs-dropdown-multiselect', []);



directiveModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselect', ['$filter', '$document', '$compile', '$parse',
    function ($filter, $document, $compile, $parse) {

        return {
            //restrict: 'AE',
            restrict: 'AEC',
            scope: {
                selectedModel: '=',
                options: '=',
                extraSettings: '=',
                events: '=',
                searchFilter: '=?',
                translationTexts: '=',
                groupBy: '@',
                fn_selectAll: '&',
                selectedId :'=',
                attrfilterProjectsonLob: '&'
            },

            template: fn_Template,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

                var $dropdownTrigger = $element.children()[0];

                $scope.toggleDropdown = function () {
                    $scope.open = !$scope.open;
                };

                $scope.checkboxClick = function ($event, id) {
                    $scope.setSelectedItem(id);
                    $event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                };

                $scope.filterProjectsonLob = function ($event, id) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.selectedId = id;
                    $scope.attrfilterProjectsonLob({value : selectedId});
                }


                $scope.externalEvents = {
                    onItemSelect: angular.noop,
                    onItemDeselect: angular.noop,
                    onSelectAll: angular.noop,
                    onDeselectAll: angular.noop,
                    onInitDone: angular.noop,
                    onMaxSelectionReached: angular.noop
                };

                $scope.settings = {
                    dynamicTitle: true,
                    scrollable: false,
                    scrollableHeight: '300px',
                    closeOnBlur: true,
                    displayProp: 'label',
                    idProp: 'id',
                    externalIdProp: 'id',
                    enableSearch: false,
                    selectionLimit: 0,
                    showCheckAll: true,
                    showUncheckAll: true,
                    closeOnSelect: false,
                    buttonClasses: 'btn btn-default',
                    closeOnDeselect: false,
                    groupBy: $attrs.groupBy || undefined,
                    groupByTextProvider: null,
                    smartButtonMaxItems: 0,
                    smartButtonTextConverter: angular.noop
                };

                $scope.texts = {
                    checkAll: 'Check All',
                    uncheckAll: 'Uncheck All',
                    selectionCount: 'checked',
                    selectionOf: '/',
                    searchPlaceholder: 'Search...',
                    buttonDefaultText: 'LOB',
                    dynamicButtonTextSuffix: 'Selected',
                    LOBSelected: ''
                };

                $scope.searchFilter = $scope.searchFilter || '';

                if (angular.isDefined($scope.settings.groupBy)) {
                    $scope.$watch('options', function (newValue) {
                        if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
                            $scope.orderedItems = $filter('orderBy')(newValue, $scope.settings.groupBy);
                        }
                    });
                }

                angular.extend($scope.settings, $scope.extraSettings || []);
                angular.extend($scope.externalEvents, $scope.events || []);
                angular.extend($scope.texts, $scope.translationTexts);

                $scope.singleSelection = $scope.settings.selectionLimit === 1;

                function getFindObj(id) {
                    var findObj = {};

                    if ($scope.settings.externalIdProp === '') {
                        findObj[$scope.settings.idProp] = id;
                    } else {
                        findObj[$scope.settings.externalIdProp] = id;
                    }

                    return findObj;
                }

                function clearObject(object) {
                    for (var prop in object) {
                        delete object[prop];
                    }
                }

                if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                    if (angular.isArray($scope.selectedModel) && $scope.selectedModel.length === 0) {
                        clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                    }
                }

                if ($scope.settings.closeOnBlur) {
                    $document.on('click', function (e) {
                        var target = e.target.parentElement;
                        var parentFound = false;

                        while (angular.isDefined(target) && target !== null && !parentFound) {
                            if (_.contains(target.className.split(' '), 'multiselect-parent') && !parentFound) {
                                if (target === $dropdownTrigger) {
                                    parentFound = true;
                                }
                            }
                            target = target.parentElement;
                        }

                        if (!parentFound) {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                $scope.open = false;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }

                $scope.getGroupTitle = function (groupValue) {
                    if ($scope.settings.groupByTextProvider !== null) {
                        return $scope.settings.groupByTextProvider(groupValue);
                    }

                    return groupValue;
                };

                $scope.getButtonText = function () {

                    if ($scope.settings.dynamicTitle && ($scope.selectedModel.length > 0 || (angular.isObject($scope.selectedModel) && _.keys($scope.selectedModel).length > 0))) {

                        //if ($scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems > 0) {

                        if ($scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems >= 0) {


                            var itemsText = [];
                            var SelectedTexts = [];

                            angular.forEach($scope.options, function (optionItem) {

                                if ($scope.isChecked($scope.getPropertyForObject(optionItem, $scope.settings.idProp))) {
                                    var displayText = $scope.getPropertyForObject(optionItem, $scope.settings.displayProp);

                                    $scope.SelectedTexts = displayText;
                                    var converterResponse = $scope.settings.smartButtonTextConverter(displayText, optionItem);

                                    itemsText.push(converterResponse ? converterResponse : displayText);
                                }
                            });

                            //if ($scope.selectedModel.length > $scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems) {
                            //    itemsText = itemsText.slice(0, $scope.settings.smartButtonMaxItems);
                            //    itemsText.push('...');
                            //}

                            if (itemsText.length <= 2) {
                                return itemsText.join(', ');
                            }

                            else {
                                var totalSelected;

                                if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                                    totalSelected = ($scope.selectedModel !== null && angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp])) ? 1 : 0;
                                } else {
                                    totalSelected = angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel) ? $scope.selectedModel.length : 0;
                                }

                                if (totalSelected === 0) {
                                    return $scope.texts.buttonDefaultText;
                                } else {


                                    return totalSelected + ' ' + $scope.texts.buttonDefaultText + ' ' + $scope.texts.dynamicButtonTextSuffix;

                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        return $scope.texts.buttonDefaultText;
                    }
                };

                $scope.getPropertyForObject = function (object, property) {
                    if (angular.isDefined(object) && object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                        return object[property];
                    }

                    return '';
                };

                $scope.selectAll = function () {

                    $scope.deselectAll(false);
                    $scope.externalEvents.onSelectAll();

                    angular.forEach($scope.options, function (value) {
                        $scope.setSelectedItem(value[$scope.settings.idProp], true);
                    });
                };

                $scope.deselectAll = function (sendEvent) {
                    sendEvent = sendEvent || true;

                    if (sendEvent) {
                        $scope.externalEvents.onDeselectAll();
                    }

                    if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                        clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                    } else {
                        $scope.selectedModel.splice(0, $scope.selectedModel.length);
                    }
                };

                $scope.setSelectedItem = function (id, dontRemove) {
                    debugger;
                    var findObj = getFindObj(id);
                    var finalObj = null;

                    if ($scope.settings.externalIdProp === '') {
                        finalObj = _.find($scope.options, findObj);
                    } else {
                        finalObj = findObj;
                    }

                    if ($scope.singleSelection) {

                        clearObject($scope.selectedModel);
                        angular.extend($scope.selectedModel, finalObj);
                        $scope.externalEvents.onItemSelect(finalObj);
                        if ($scope.settings.closeOnSelect) $scope.open = false;

                        return;
                    }

                    dontRemove = dontRemove || false;

                    var exists = _.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, findObj) !== -1;



                    if (!dontRemove && exists) {
                        $scope.selectedModel.splice(_.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, findObj), 1);
                        $scope.externalEvents.onItemDeselect(findObj);
                    } else if (!exists && ($scope.settings.selectionLimit === 0 || $scope.selectedModel.length < $scope.settings.selectionLimit)) {
                        $scope.selectedModel.push(finalObj);
                        $scope.externalEvents.onItemSelect(finalObj);
                    }
                    if ($scope.settings.closeOnSelect) $scope.open = false;
                };

                $scope.isChecked = function (id) {
                    if ($scope.singleSelection) {
                        return $scope.selectedModel !== null && angular.isDefined($scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp]) && $scope.selectedModel[$scope.settings.idProp] === getFindObj(id)[$scope.settings.idProp];
                    }
                    return _.findIndex($scope.selectedModel, getFindObj(id)) !== -1;
                };

                $scope.externalEvents.onInitDone();
            }
        };
    }]);

function fn_Template(element, attrs) {
    var checkboxes = attrs.checkboxes ? true : false;
    var groups = attrs.groupBy ? true : false;


    var template = '<div class="multiselect-parent btn-group dropdown-multiselect">';
    template += '<button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-class="settings.buttonClasses" ng-click="toggleDropdown()">{{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>';
    template += '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form" ng-style="{display: open ? \'block\' : \'none\', height : settings.scrollable ? settings.scrollableHeight : \'auto\' }" style="overflow: scroll" >';
    template += '<li ng-hide="!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0"><a data-ng-click="selectAll()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>  {{texts.checkAll}}</a>';
    template += '<li ng-show="settings.showUncheckAll"><a data-ng-click="deselectAll();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>   {{texts.uncheckAll}}</a></li>';
    template += '<li ng-hide="(!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0) && !settings.showUncheckAll" class="divider"></li>';
    template += '<li ng-show="settings.enableSearch"><div class="dropdown-header"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="{{texts.searchPlaceholder}}" /></li>';
    template += '<li ng-show="settings.enableSearch" class="divider"></li>';

    if (groups) {
        template += '<li ng-repeat-start="option in orderedItems | filter: searchFilter" ng-show="getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy) !== getPropertyForObject(orderedItems[$index - 1], settings.groupBy)" role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">{{ getGroupTitle(getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy)) }}</li>';
        template += '<li ng-repeat-end role="presentation">';
    } else {
        template += '<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in options | filter: searchFilter">';
    }


    template += '<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="setSelectedItem(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))">';

    if (checkboxes) {
        template += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkboxClick($event, getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp));  filterProjectsonLob($event, getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp)) "ng-checked="isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))" /> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</label></div></a>';
    } else {
        template += '<span data-ng-class="{\'glyphicon glyphicon-ok\': isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))}"></span> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</a>';
    }

    template += '</li>';

    template += '<li class="divider" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"></li>';
    template += '<li role="presentation" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"><a role="menuitem">{{selectedModel.length}} {{texts.selectionOf}} {{settings.selectionLimit}} {{texts.selectionCount}}</a></li>';

    template += '</ul>';
    template += '</div>';

    element.html(template);
}
```

Comments
----------   .
Please guide me what is wrong i am doing,  as controllers method is not getting invoked.
I need to call  $scope.getProjects method  present in controller from $scope.filterProjectsonLob in directive. Please guide me as i am new to angularJs.

Comment: $scope.$parent.getProjects

Comment: you need to call `$scope.attrfilterProjectsonLob({selectedId : Id});` in your filterProjectsonLob  method

Answer (score 0):

Your directive can have it's own controller:

```
angular.directive(function() { //blah blah
  return {
    //restrict: 'AE',
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
    },
    controller: multiselect,
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  }
});
```

Then it's a matter of vm.methodNameCall(arguments) as you would normally do.

Comment: Thanks, but i need to put  the controller  in different file,

Comment: @NavinRane you can still have your controller in a different file as long as they're part of the same module or the directive's module injects the controller's module.

Comment: @rrd this approach would give each `ngDropdownMultiselect` its own controller rather than sharing a single controller between them.

Comment: @plong0 I agree, it would, but avoiding code bloat is also a consideration.

Comment: It wouldn't take much extra code to simply wrap multiselect controller into a directive (as I explain in my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your controller is existing on the parent scope of your directive and the directive has an isolate scope so it doesn't see its parent scope's data.

The simplest solution (but not necessarily most correct) is to use `$scope.$parent` (`$scope.$parent.getProjects`) from inside your directive to access the controller's scope.

A more correct solution is to refactor your `multiselect` controller to be a directive.  With multiselect as a directive (ex. `ngMultiselect`), you would be able to inject its controller into other directives.  You won't need to change your controller code that much, just make a directive with it as a controller rather than use `ng-controller`.

Step 1: replace ng-controller with `ngMultiselect` directive.

```
directiveModule.directive('ngMultiselect', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        controller: 'multiselect'
    };
});
```

`<div class="row" ng-app="myModule" ng-multiselect> ... </div>`

Step 2: update `multiselect` controller to expose `getProjects` function

```
// change:
$scope.getProjects = function (selectedId) {...};

// to:
this.getProjects = function (selectedId) {...};

// and if you still need getProjects on multiselect's scope, you can add $scope.getProjects = this.getProjects;
```

Step 3: Inject controller into `ngDropdownMultiselect` by requiring `ngMultiselect`

```
directiveModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselect', ['$filter', '$document', '$compile', '$parse',
    function ($filter, $document, $compile, $parse) {

        return {
            //restrict: 'AE',
            restrict: 'AEC',
            require: 'ngMultiselect',
            scope: {
                selectedModel: '=',
                options: '=',
                // etc ...
            },

            template: fn_Template,
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, MultiselectCtrl) {
                $scope.getProjects = MultiselectCtrl.getProjects;

                // and the rest of your stuff here...
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Learning how to set up and differentiate controllers + directive link functions is certainly one of the finer points of learning angular.  I would say it is necessary for building anything beyond simple components.  There are lots of tutorials about it, but it can be tricky to really grok until you come across it in your own codings.

Edit:
Just wanted to note that you will need to take a look at which modules you are defining your directives and controller in and set your module dependencies accordingly.

Comment: Thank u very much @plong0... Great solution by you... Thank u very much

Comment: Glad that it helps you, @NavinRane!